# no suitable method found for addAll

Tags: java

Given the following Java code:

```
public void addStuff(Collection<? extends Object> aCollection) {
    List<? extends Object> myList = new LinkedList<>(aCollection);
    myList.addAll(aCollection);
}
```

The constructor call compiles, but the addAll() call fails to compile. I get the following error:

```
no suitable method found for addAll(Collection<CAP#1>)
    method Collection.addAll(Collection<? extends CAP#2>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Collection<CAP#1> cannot be converted to Collection<? extends CAP#2>)
    method List.addAll(Collection<? extends CAP#2>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Collection<CAP#1> cannot be converted to Collection<? extends CAP#2>)
  where CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ? extends Object
    CAP#2 extends Object from capture of ? extends Object
```

Even though they have the same signature, and one calls the other:

```
public LinkedList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    this();
    addAll(c);
}

public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    return addAll(size, c);
}
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically: wildcards are wonky, and Java doesn't assume that the wildcards are the same wildcard.  In `List<? extends Object>`, that's considered to be a different `?` than the other one.

You could make this work by naming the type:

```
public <E> void addStuff(Collection<E> aCollection) {
  List<E> myList = new LinkedList<>(aCollection);
  myList.addAll(aCollection);
}
```